# Google appengine mail api sending out multiple emails consecutively

Tags: php, email, google-app-engine

I have deployed my application in Google appengine. The form data entered by the user is emailed to me and I use mail api provided by Google app engine. However, this seems to work fine but when the submit button is pressed I receive 8 mails consecutively and only one email consists of valid data ,the others are just empty without the form data.
I have also authorized the sender email in the appengine project console.

This is my email.php script.

```
<?php
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';

use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;   //line 6 in my code

$name = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$textBody= "You have received a new message from your website Name: $name\n\";

$mail_options = [
    "sender" => " user@webapp.appspotmail.com",
    "to" => "userjow@gmail.com",
    "subject" => "You have a new message from your website.",
       ];

try {
    $message = new Message($mail_options);
    $message->send();
    echo "Thankyou for your Message";
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {

}
 ?>
```

Comment: You should add some validation and ensure that at least some fields are filled out before sending

Comment: I often see favicon requests hitting primary front controllers unless you have excluded in your app.yaml. Also +1 on the form validation!!